# Unable to execute ssh command containing parentheses with perl: "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Tags: bash, perl

If I run this command from the command line, it works as expected on the remote server:

```
ssh admin@example.com "docker exec -it -d tasks_live_work_ec2_test_server /bin/sh -c \"/usr/bin/nvim -c 'silent! call SetupInstantServer()'\""
```

However, if I try to execute it from a perl script, I get errors:

```
my $cmd = qq|docker exec -it -d ${image_name}_server /bin/sh -c \"/usr/bin/nvim -c 'silent! call SetupInstantServer()'\"|;
    `ssh admin\@example.com "$cmd"`;
```

```
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token '('`
```

Escaping the parens with backslashes suppresses the error, but the `SetupInstantServer` function in vim never gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do, using 2 *here-doc*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system<<PerlEOF;
    ssh admin\@example.com<<ShellEOF
        docker exec -it -d ${image_name}_server /bin/sh -c "
            /usr/bin/nvim -c 'silent! call SetupInstantServer()'
        "
ShellEOF
PerlEOF
```

You can decide to add quotes on a **'HereDoc'** to prevent shell expansion or the need to escape `@`. Up to your needs.

Check [perldoc perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Comment: Worked! I just get a weird message output when run: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. blah blah blah`. I'll just divert to null. Thanks!

Comment: Try `ssh -t` ...

Comment: I tried -t and it didn't seem to work. Maybe I was using it wrong.

Comment: It's just a warning AFAIK